# Clementine cannot access music on a NAS share - true or false?

Tags: music, nas

There are many references to this problem in various forums, but there seems to be no solution. What baffles me is that, if there is a solution to this problem for, say, Rhythmbox, what is it about Clementine that prevents a similar fix? 
(I'm doubly puzzled because the (shhh!) Windows version of Clementine has no such problem.) Am I wasting my time trying to get Clementine to do what you would think was now a fairly routine trick?

Comment: How do you access the NAS? If you mounted it, Clementine should be able to access it without problems.

Comment: I don't think I know the answer to that. Its content is visible through Nautilus. How would I go about mounting a NAS - what would look different if I did?

Comment: You might want to check out Clementine's successor, Strawberry https://www.strawberrymusicplayer.org.

Answer (score 0):

You could *mount* the NAS instead of using Samba (which I assume you do):

1. Install cifs: `sudo apt-get install cifs-utils`.
2. Create a directory to mount the NAS, e.g. `sudo mkdir /mnt/mynasdrive`
3. Mount the drive to the location: `sudo mount //hostname/drive -o username=<username>,password=<password>,rw,nounix,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0644,dir_mode=0755 /mnt/mynasdrive`. Replace `<username>` and `<password>` by the corresponding access data or leave the whole username and password section (everyting between `-o` and `rw`) away, if the drive is accessed anonymously.
4. Now you should be able to access the drive at `/mnt/mynasdrive`, so Clementine should be able to do so, too.
5. To unmount it again, simply run `sudo umount /dev/mynasdrive`.

Source: http://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/procedure/mount-nas-storage-linux
The linked site also explains how to add the drive to the fstab, so it can be mounted on boot, but I think this would exceed an answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

I have a partial answer:  mounting the drive is certainly one way, but a pain.  When using nautilus you can have clementine access the drive **after** you've mounted it in nautilus.  This works because nautilus mounts the drive via gvfs and you can then use this mount point in clementine...it just works.

OTOH, it's not possible in KDE environment using Dolphin as it does not properly mount it as far as I can see, so have to revert to a manual / FSTAB mount which is a PITA.

It would be nice if Clementine could just access via a URL, e.g. smb://192.......

Strawberry behaves in the same way.